# How to use xamarin with c# visual studio 2022 personal and unity editor 2D Mobile Core project?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, xamarin

What I'm trying to do is to control my phone flashlight through the unity editor.

I can build now the project in Android platform and when running it I can see a ui slider I added to the unity editor hierarchy.  but now I want to use the slider in a c# script to control the phone flashlight light intensity.

this is the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Xamarin.Essentials;

public class LightsIntensity : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Flashlight.TurnOnAsync();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

but I'm getting error on the line:

`using Xamarin.Essentials;`

The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

but it did recognized it some minutes before and when I make in the solution explorer right click with the mouse and Manage NuGet Packages for Solution... in Browse I see that Xamarin.Essentials is already installed.

I also installed it in the unity editor to be able to use the Android platform when building.

What am I missing and then how do I use it in the script to control the phone flashlight light intensity with the ui slider?

Screenshot image of the unity editor:

https://imgur.com/a/payCjvO

I can't upload the image to the stackoverflow so I added it to the imgur.

What I have tried so far is to installed the Xamarin package but now getting the error.

Comment: Modifications to the generated solution do not carry over to Unity. You need to add the assembly on the Unity side.

Answer (score 0):

Close Visual Studio, navigate to your solution directory and then go through each of your solution folders and delete the contents of all `bin` and `obj` folders.

Open Visual Studio and your solution, and run a full rebuild.

This should solve the issue.